# Find and replace with column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this task. I have column A and B. Column A1 contains a text value "Shared Service". Column B1 contains the text value "Shared".

What I want to do is remove the "Shared" part of "Shared Service" so all that's left is "Service". I need to do this for many different values in column A/B though.

Is there any easy way to automate this? It's basically just a mass find and replace with a blank value, it just needs to be based off the values in column B.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the replies but these solutions assume the columns line up side to side. To clarify, I need to look for ALL values in column B and remove ALL of them from column A. So the "of vat" line would become "of" in this example (it finds the "vat" value from column B and removes it from A). This has to be done with 1000s of different values.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Formula - `=TRIM(SUSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))`

Comment: Yep, there are lots of ways to do this. If you already have code, post it.  If not, the macro recorder is a good start.

Comment: vba - `[A:A] = [INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,B:B,"")),)]`

Comment: Thanks for the help but my column values won't be side to side (see update).

Comment: You have service and center so would A3 be nothing?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like you might want a *collection*.  I see something like this as a starting point:

```
Sub RemoveWords(DeleteFromCol As Range, FindCol As Range)

  Dim words As New Collection
  Dim r As Range
  Dim word As Variant

  For Each r In FindCol
    words.Add (r.Value2)
  Next r

  For Each r In DeleteFromCol
    For Each word In words
      r.Value2 = Replace(r.Value2, word, "")
    Next word
  Next r

End Sub
```

And then you could invoke it with aribitrary ranges, in your example:

```
RemoveWords Range("A1:A11"), Range("B1:B8")
```

I'm guessing this may not be 100%, as in your example I would purge both words in some cases, since they exist in the "one word" list.  You can handle that however you want.